# Why in C# break is required in switch loop after default case?

Tags: c#, switch-statement, default, break

After `default`, control is supposed to automatically come out of `switch loop`. But C# requires use of a break statement? Why in C# control is not automatically coming out of `switch loop` after `default`?

The following microsoft doc say so: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch

In my code:

```
using System;

class Program {
static void Main() {
    Console.WriteLine("Enter a number between 1 and 10");
    int num;
    bool validity = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out num);
    if(validity==true) {
        switch(num) {
            case 1:
            case 2:
            case 3:
            case 4:
            case 5:
            case 6:
            case 7:
            case 8:
            case 9:
            case 10:

                Console.WriteLine("You have entered {0}", num);
                break;
            default:
                Console.WriteLine("You have not entered a number between 1 and 10");
                //break; This part is commented
        }
    } 
    else {
        Console.WriteLine("Please make a valid input");
    }
}
}
```

It gives me the error -

> (23,5): error CS8070: Control cannot fall out of switch from final case label ('default:')

But on uncommenting the break part the code works fine.

Comment: The C# language specification just prohibits control from ever reaching the `}` of a switch statement. That makes all the cases more consistent with each other, and means they're easier to reorder. The fact that your `default` case is last is just a coincidence here.

Comment: Note that `break` is not the only way to achieve this. `throw new Exception();` will also prevent control from reaching the `}`. You would not require `break` then.

Comment: This is similar to the other question, but it seems to be a little distinct from it.  The other question deals with the last case in general, but this one deals specifically with `default`.  The answers on the other question dealt mainly with the fact that requiring a `break` statement on the last case can often help with refactoring and consistency, which is true if that last label isn't `default`.  They didn't seem to address why an exception was not provided in the language for `default` though.

Answer (score 3):

```
switch(num) {
    case 1:
        DoSomething();
    case 2:
        DoSomething2();
    case 3:
    case 4:
    case 5:
        Console.WriteLine("You have entered {0}", num);
        break;
    default:
        Console.WriteLine("You have not entered a number between 1 and 10");
        //break; This part is commented
    case 6:
        DoSomething3();
}
```

In above code in case 1 you want only `DoSomething()` or `DoSomething()` and go to case `2`? To avoid such mistakes (forgotten break).

You can have after `default` block another case and you can forgot add break.

Comment: C# prohibits fall-through except for empty cases (such as your 3 and 4 here).

Comment: This needs a `break` in case 1, case 2, default, and case 6. I'm not sure what point is being made here.